# Implement iptables that drops ACK packet but accepts it for a client

Tags: linux, networking, iptables

I have an IoT-device (called Device A in image below) that communicates with my server through a router. However, once in a while my IoT device gets a WDT and restarts and from my investigation it seems to be related to the network traffic and how I handle things in my IoT-device. From the snippet below, we can see that Device A and the Server communicates good until my device sends an ack that my server does not receives and starts sending PSH, ACK multiple times before Device A sends a Keep-Alive.

This is superhard to debug since it only happens like once every other day or less than that. My question is therefore, can I somehow with the help of iptables configure my computer (acting as a router with DHCP and forward to my other interface for internet) that it drops every X (30 or so) ACK packet but Device A sees it as a sent packet? Or is this a TCP/IP stack issue?

Also, I tried these rules to simulate a restart of the iface with these iptables rules, are they correct or should I do it in another fashion?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> My question is therefore, can I somehow with the help of iptables configure my computer (acting as a router with DHCP and forward to my other interface for internet) that it drops every X (30 or so) ACK packet but Device A sees it as a sent packet?

Yes, literally by configuring iptables to drop the packet as you normally do. If you use the `-j DROP` verdict, the sending host will not receive any ICMP errors about the packet not being delivered.

(IP does not use any kind of "packet accepted" indication, so the sending host *always* sees the packet as "sent" as soon as it leaves the original host.)

To drop just a single ACK you could use a `--connbytes` match, or a `--mode nth --packet X` match, or any other suitable match that you find in "man iptables-extensions".

Make sure to insert your rule in the FORWARD chain *above* any `--state ESTABLISHED` rules (as those would implicitly accept all TCP ACKs).

Comment: Thanks! That worked like a charm, however I realized now that dropping the packages might not resemble the tcpdump-image. I've been going over that over and over again and something that stands out to me is that after the ACK seq=289825, ack=187276 from Device A, the server starts to send multiple empty PSH ACK seq=177276, ack=289825, but shouldn't the seq number be equal to the last ack number?

Comment: It's the opposite, ack is equal to the last seq (it _acknowledges receipt_ of the seq). So the ack=187276 from Device A confirms the previously received seq=187276 from the server. I'm not sure why the server then starts sending packets with a lower seq than has already been acknowledged (unless you've dropped that ack?)

Comment: Yeah, you are totally right about the seq/ack, blames my tired head... But I agree, I've no idea why the servers starts doing that, since this shouldn't have dropped any ack here, at least to my knowledge. I don't know if it has something todo with the router missing a packet somehow?